# Are rspec controller tests in a Rails 5 Api still common?

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I try to setup a new Rails 5.2.1 "Api only"-app.

While following some tutorials I was surprised that a lot of them (if not all) are only writing request specs. What I also found is the `type: :api` option in some of their tutorials.

What is the difference in `type: :request` and `type: :api` ?

1. So I am a bit confused. Is this common practice to drop controller specs?
2. Or is logic tested in request specs instead of controller specs?, because of no view logic?

   ```
   RSpec.describe 'Authentications', type: :request do
    ...
   end

   RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :api do
    ...
   end
   ```

Thank you in advance

Comment: controller tests are shallow and do not go through middleware/routes so most folks avoid them now.  I don't know what `api` is, it's probably a custom attribute.

Comment: @Anthony, yes you are right it seems to be that "api" is a custom type people are using. I try now to avoid controller specs, but they are still generated by scaffolding

Comment: This seems relevant: [Controller Specs vs Request Specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40851705/controller-specs-vs-request-specs). Consensus was that controller specs are passe.