# How to create update test with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was creating the update test

```
describe 'PUT /update' do
      context "update a Article" do

        it 'update ' do
          put "/api/v1/posts/#{@post.id}/articles/#{@article.id}", article =>{name: "n"}
          expect { @patient.name }.to eq("ABCD1")
        end
      end
    end
```

but i am getting

```
ArgumentError:
       unknown keyword: #<Article id: 1,
```

Comment: @spickermann can you help me with this question more please

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the `, article =>{name: "n"}` part in the line in which you do the query. It is not entirely clear to me what you try to achieve there, but I guess you want to pass a new article name as a `params`. Another issue will certainly be the next line, because why expecting a specific `@patient.document_id` when you changed a `@article`?

Try this:

```
describe 'PUT /update' do
  context "update a Article" do
    it 'update the article as expected' do
      put("/api/v1/posts/#{@post.id}/articles/#{@article.id}", 
          params: article: { name: "new name" })

      expect { @article.name }.to eq("new name")
    end
  end
end
```